# Type ahead only displaying one value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use typeahead with json but am not having much success.  Whichever movie name that I type in, it always displays 'Kick Ass'.  So for example, I also have 'Blade Runner' in my database, I type in 'Blade' but the typeahead displays 'Kick Ass'.

Advice appreciated.

View:

```
@section scripts
{
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var movies = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('Name'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            remote: {
                url: '/movies/AllMovies?query=%QUERY',
                wildcard: '%QUERY',

            }
        });

        $('#Movie_Name').typeahead({
            minLength: 3,
            highlight: true
    }, {

        name: 'movies',
        display: 'Name',
        source: movies

            });

    });

    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
 public JsonResult AllMovies()
        {
            return Json(_context.Movies.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

JsonResult:

```
[{"Id":9,"Name":"Kick Ass","Genre":null,"GenreId":1,"DateAdded":"\/Date(1488499200000)\/","ReleaseDate":"\/Date(1269561600000)\/","NumberInStock":5,"NumberAvailable":0,"ImagePath":"~/Content/images/kickassthumb.jpg"},{"Id":11,"Name":"Star Trek Beyond","Genre":null,"GenreId":6,"DateAdded":"\/Date(1488758400000)\/","ReleaseDate":"\/Date(1469142000000)\/","NumberInStock":10,"NumberAvailable":0,"ImagePath":"~/Content/images/StarTrekBeyondthumb.jpg"},{"Id":12,"Name":"Blade Runner","Genre":null,"GenreId":6,"DateAdded":"\/Date(1489594314620)\/","ReleaseDate":"\/Date(400374000000)\/","NumberInStock":5,"NumberAvailable":0,"ImagePath":"~/Content/images/bladerunnerthumb.jpg"},{"Id":13,"Name":"Deadpool","Genre":null,"GenreId":1,"DateAdded":"\/Date(1489595002103)\/","ReleaseDate":"\/Date(1455062400000)\/","NumberInStock":5,"NumberAvailable":0,"ImagePath":"~/Content/images/deadpoolthumb.jpg"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use typehead's substringMatcher(source) method? you can do something like

```
{
    name: 'someName',
    source: substringMatcher(source)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `_conext` isn't mapped to a mock repository. Your issue doesn't seem to have anything to do with typeahead as it is working exactly as expected considering the response from your service call.